# Android Runtime permission in Cordova 3.6 App

Tags: cordova, hybrid-mobile-app, android-runtime

How to implement android runtime permissions in app that is using **cordova 3.5**

Comment: does https://github.com/NeoLSN/cordova-plugin-android-permissions work?

Answer (score 0):

Android Runtime permission introduced from [Android 6.0 (API level 23)](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html). It has no relation with cordova version.

In MainActivity.java of your Android platform, add this code after `loadUrl(launchUrl);`

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23)
{
    // Sample request for user permission runtime */
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
            new String[] {                      
                    android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
            },
            100);        
}
```

If you are working on android studio it will automatically import necessary packages like:

```
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
```

Comment: Thanks Avijit , But mine is hybrid app that uses  cordova 3.5